# How to capture worker and health data in locust headless mode

Tags: locust

I am running one test with locust in distributed mode. I want to capture the master and worker health data in a csv after the test. Also want to see the worker and master health data in the console during the execution at an interval of 5 secs.

I found this code on internet but it is not working

```
def on_worker_report(environment, data):
    # Extract worker health data
    worker_id = data["client_id"]
    cpu_usage = data["cpu_usage"]
    memory_usage = data["memory_usage"]

    # Perform actions with the worker health data (e.g., logging, storing, etc.)

def on_master_report(environment, data):
    # Extract master health data
    cpu_usage = data["cpu_usage"]
    memory_usage = data["memory_usage"]

    # Perform actions with the master health data (e.g., logging, storing, etc.)

# Register the event listeners
events.worker_report.add_listener(on_worker_report)
events.master_report.add_listener(on_master_report)
```

Please help me with the resolution

Comment: What's wrong with this code? What behavior do you see with it when you use it?